# use ref for parent elements in dynamic blocks React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Can you please tell me how to do the ref on the parent block correctly

I just know that using selectors in virtualDom is wrong, I need to use refs

How to make refs to replace selectors in methods addTag and editTags?

```js
class Home extends Component {

    editTags = (e) => {
        e.target.closest('.card-list__item--tags').classList.add('active');
    }

    addTag = (e) => {
        let tagFieldValue = e.target.closest('.card-list__item_edit').querySelector('input');
        let indexItem = e.target.closest('.card-list__item').id;
        let cardList = this.props.cards;
        cardList[indexItem].tags = cardList[indexItem].tags + ', ' + tagFieldValue.value;
        this.props.onEditTags(cardList);
        tagFieldValue.value = '';
        e.target.closest('.card-list__item--tags').classList.remove('active');
    }




    render(){
        let cardList = this.props.cards;

        return(
            <div className={'card-list'}>
                {
                    cardList.length && cardList.map((card, index) =>
                        <div id={index} className={'card-list__item'}>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--tags'}>
                                <div className={'tags-wrap'} onDoubleClick={this.editTags}>
                                    {
                                        card.tags.split(', ').map((tag) =>
                                            <span>{tag}</span>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </div>
                                <div className={'card-list__item_edit'}>
                                    <input id={index} type="text" placeholder={'Add tags'}/>
                                    <button onClick={this.addTag}>Add Tag</button>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Home;
```

Comment: so it’s generally possible to do it, otherwise I don’t see such variation in the use of refs anywhere?

Comment: no one knows what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using React 16.10.0 and higher you can use refs like this:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.cardListRef = React.createRef();
  }

  addTag = (e) => {
    const cardListRefNode = this.cardListRef.current;
    console.log(cardListRefNode); // card-list node will be available here
    let tagFieldValue = e.target.closest('.card-list__item_edit').querySelector('input');
    let indexItem = e.target.closest('.card-list__item').id;
    let cardList = this.props.cards;
    cardList[indexItem].tags = cardList[indexItem].tags + ', ' + tagFieldValue.value;
    this.props.onEditTags(cardList);
    tagFieldValue.value = '';
    e.target.closest('.card-list__item--tags').classList.remove('active');
  }

  render(){
        let cardList = this.props.cards;

        return(
            <div className={'card-list'} ref={this.cardListRef}>
                {
                    cardList.length && cardList.map((card, index) =>
                        <div id={index} className={'card-list__item'}>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--tags'}>
                                <div className={'tags-wrap'} onDoubleClick={this.editTags}>
                                    {
                                        card.tags.split(', ').map((tag) =>
                                            <span>{tag}</span>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </div>
                                <div className={'card-list__item_edit'}>
                                    <input id={index} type="text" placeholder={'Add tags'}/>
                                    <button onClick={this.addTag}>Add Tag</button>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

But as I see you are using selectors to get value from input, to clear the input and to switch classes. Refs were created in React for another purpose (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs).

It looks like in your case it's better to use component's state for such tasks. You can get values from inputs with onChange event, and then you can store these values in the component's state.
Also, it would be better to move "'card-list__item'" to a separate component and switch active class in it depending on its state too. You can find more examples of how to work with forms in React here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html